# Sum of number of factors of first N numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, factoring, prime-factorization

Given a number N ( Value can be large like N < 10^9 ) How can we calculate sum of the number of factors of first N numbers??

Example :

For n = 3

Answer:

1. = #f(1) + #f(2) + #f(3)  ---   { #f(n) -> number of factors of n }

   ```
      = 1 + 2 + 2
      = 5
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is contained in the wikipedia article on the [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).  In particular, using the traditional notation of $d(n)$ to represent the number of divisors of $n$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N d(n) = N \ln N + (2 \gamma - 1) N + O(\sqrt{N}),
$$
where $\gamma \approx 0.5772$ is Euler's constant.  The error can be improved, and conjecturally is $O(N^{1/4})$.

Comment: If you can prove the error is $O(N^{1/4})$, I will be impressed. You will probably also get a Field's or Abel prize.

Comment: Haha, I can't prove it is $O(N^{1/2 - \epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, even though it is known in the literature to be so.  The word 'conjecturally' is in my last sentence for a reason. :)

Comment: I want the answer as a whole number.. I dont want approximations

Comment: Well there's no closed formula for the sum, so the best you can do is write a simple program to compute the sum.